# Calculating size of Mac OS directory with resource forks without using deprecated functions

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mavericks, osx-mountain-lion, file-forks

I would like to calculate the size of a directory and all its contents. All the solutions that I've come across either use NSFileManager (which doesn't take resource forks into account when calculating the file size) or [this carbon code](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/136498-obtain-directory-size.html#136503) which uses deprecated functions.

How should we now get an accurate folder size using Cocoa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this:

```
- (unsigned long long)folderSizeForURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSArray *keys = @[ NSURLTotalFileSizeKey ];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                         enumeratorAtURL:url
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                         options:0
                                         errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                             // Handle the error.
                                             // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                             return YES;
                                         }];

    unsigned long long size = 0;

    for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
        NSError *error;
        NSNumber *totalFileSize;
        [url getResourceValue:&totalFileSize forKey:NSURLTotalFileSizeKey error:&error];

        size += [totalFileSize longLongValue];
    }

    return size;
}
```

The result is exactly the same as the finder.